# generate sequence of (telephone) numbers in table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my first post/question since I couldn't find the answer to what I was looking for no matter how I searched. So here it is:

I have a small table of a few hundred rows with four columns (plus id col) as seen on the example below:

```
| id | phone1 | phone2 | phone3   | phone4 |
| 1  |059374-6|        | 065371-7 |023126-8 
| 2  |        |026372-3| 024353-7 |
| 3  |...
.
.
.
```

I need to generate the sequence for all the (telephone) numbers of the specific range they belong. In other words, for the first phone number I need to retrieve the numbers:

```
059374
059375
059376
```

and consequently for the rest of the phones in the table.

All the number ranges are given in the above mentioned form and do not exceed the total of 10 numbers (max is something like 099500-9). In addition, they are populated through 4 different columns, as shown in the above example, something I have solved so far by using UNION ALL (in order to put them all in one column and finally find all duplicates which is the ultimate goal).
So, is there any elegant way to generate the numbers needed?
I have searched many threads for similar topics but surprisingly none seem to answer my question.

Finally, if there is any better way than combining all cols into one with UNION ALL and then GROUP BY col1 for finding the duplicates would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not something that's easy to do in SQL. Use a programming language that has loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table that contains the numbers from 0 to 9. Extract the starting and ending digits of each number, and join with the number table to find all the numbers in the range.

```
WITH digits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS dig
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS dig
    ...
    UNION 
    SELECT 9 AS dig)
SELECT SUBSTR(phone1, 1, 5) + digits.dig
FROM yourTable
JOIN digits ON dig BETWEEN SUBSTR(phone1, 6, 1) AND SUBSTR(phone1, 8, 1)
WHERE phone1 != ''
```

This shows how to do it for the `phone1` column, you can use `UNION` to repeat it for the other 3 columns.

Comment: Wow! Your approach was really groundbreaking!
I was sure there had to be a better way. I tried it and it although it did bring a nice result set, was not exactly the correct one. Only the phone numbers ending in 0 were returning correct results. So, I changed it a a little bit from "SELECT SUBSTR(phone1, 1, 5) + digits.dig" to "SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTR(phone1, 1, 5) , dig) " and... voila!

Thank you for the logic behind. I will vote for your answer.

PS: there are very few cases where a phone ends up to sth like xxxx19-23 (there are really few so I didn't mention them). Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to vote for you answer but I don't have the necessary reputation. :(  In any case, thank you very much for solving my problem. 

PS: I also managed to figure out how to approach numbers ending in two digits (like xxx19-23) by creating a two digit column on the digits table and joining them on the two digits before and after the dash of the phone column. Thanks again!